# javax.security.cert.X509Certificate vs java.security.cert.X509Certificate?

Tags: java, security, certificate

Did you spot the difference in the title? (for me, it took some time)

So I used bouncy castle with connection to `java.security.cert.X509Certificate` in order
to create certificates. Now I'm looking for a way to create a `java.security.cert.X509Certificate` from raw bytes. I haven't any method to do this in
`java.security.cert.X509Certificate` but there is one(the getInstance static method) in
`javax.security.cert.X509Certificate`.

The problem is I cannot cast a `javax.security.cert.X509Certificate` to `java.security.cert.X509Certificate`.

Any ideas on what to do, to transform raw bytes into a `java.security.cert.X509Certificate`?

Also, what's the differences between the one abstract class and the other class? Why does java has two of them with different functionality?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The javax version is deprecated. Use [CertificateFactory](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/cert/CertificateFactory.html) to generate a certificate from raw bytes. There is an example in the javadocs.

Comment: Where is it deprecated? I looked at the Java 8 javadoc for both the java. and javax. versions and none mentions any deprecation.

Comment: OK, In Java 9 javadoc it is actually marked as deprecated (Java 9 appeared years after this answer... in 2017)

Answer (score 11):

This happened for me because I am using j2se but imported javax classes.
Certificate and X509Certficate classes exists both in J2SE and in J2EE.

## Imports in J2SE - Not javax.security...

```
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.cert.CertificateFactory;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
```

## import java.security.cert.Certificate;

Not these.

```
import javax.security.cert.X509Certificate;
```